# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gensim'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, python-import, gensim

My goal is to import gensim in Python 3 on Windows.

I am using Python 3.7.2 (checked by running `python -V` in Windows command prompt). I installed gensim by running `pip install gensim`. I checked the installation by running `pip freeze`, and saw the line `gensim==3.7.3`.

Then, I ran the command `py` to enter the interactive python mode (still in Windows command prompt). I ran the line `import gensim` and got the following output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gensim'
```

I also tried `from gensim import test` and got the following output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gensim'
```

Any suggestions? How do I install gensim on Windows with Python 3? How do I test gensim?

Comment: Is your system able to work with both `py` and `python` command? If yes then chances are there are two different compilers of python in your system

Comment: Yes, I am able to enter the interactive mode with both `py` and `python`. How do I go about fixing this issue and having only one python compiler on my system?

Comment: try running `py -m pip freeze` and see whether there exists `gensim` module or not

Comment: Some food for thought with `ModuleNotFoundError`. Always use a `virtual environment`. In case you don't know how to use it. spend some time & learn it. The rewards are immeasurable!

Answer (score 2):

In Mac, open anaconda navigator, Click on 'Open Terminal option'. If you are using Windows, Run anaconda prompt as administrator and run the following command:

[image]

`conda install -c conda-forge gensim`

Answer (score 1):

I think you have installed it using normal cmd, so it may have installed it on python2.x. Install it with anaconda prompt.

Let me know if it worked for you.

Comment: How do I check this theory? That is, how do I check if it is installed on Python 2.x or Python 3.x? How do I get started with Anaconda?

Comment: If you have installed anaconda distribution then if you search anaconda, you will see Anaconda Prompt. One other alternative is run this command in jupyter notebook with symbol `!` in start.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error after installing gensim in Anaconda. It worked only after I re-started the Anaconda: by exiting it, and re-opening it via the command prompt. I wanted to share this experience since someone else may meet the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

To understand why this happens, you must know how Windows finds executables to run, and how the Python software is installed.

- When running a command, Windows searches for an executable in the environment variable PATH. It executes the first one found.
- `python.exe` is installed in `<PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR>` (e.g. `C:\Python\3.7`).
- `pip.exe` and other Python tools (e.g. `pylint`, `virtualenv`, `pycrust`, etc.) are installed in `<PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR>\Scripts`.
- `py.exe` is installed in your Windows system directory (e.g. `C:\Windows`).
- `python` and `pip` commands use the modules found in the directory their installed in, they do not look at PATH.

So, let's say you have the following Python versions:

```
C:\Python\2.7
C:\Python\3.6
C:\Python\3.7
```

and your PATH environment contains the following directories:

```
C:\Python\2.7
C:\Python\3.6\Scripts
```

then, see the following output:

```
C:\>python -V
Python 2.7.16

C:\>pip -V
pip 19.1.1 from c:\python\3.6\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.6)

C:\>py -V
Python 3.7.3
```

So, when running `pip`, it is possible that the packages are installed in another Python version then the version you'll get when running `python`.

To see which versions are (correctly) installed on your system, run `py -0p`. Example output:

```
C:\>py -0p
Installed Pythons found by py Launcher for Windows
 -3.7-64        C:\Python\3.7-64\python.exe *
 -3.7-32        C:\Python\3.7-32\python.exe
 -3.6-64        C:\Python\3.6-64\python.exe
 -2.7-64        C:\Python\2.7-64\python.exe
 -2.7-32        C:\Python\2.7-32\python.exe
```

**General solution (for Windows)**

The best thing is not to rely on your system PATH. Use the `py` launcher to select the version you want. To run the `pip` module corresponding to the Python version you want to use, start `pip` as a module instead of executable.
So instead of:

```
pip install <package>
```

run:

```
py -3.6 -m pip install <package>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's My hypothesis towards your situation, since your OS is able to recognize both `python` and `py` commands in commandline, this may mean that you have two separate versions of python installed.

Since, as you mentioned that `python -V` shows `gensim` as an installed module. Try opening python interactive interpreter via command `python` instead of `py`, and import `gensim` module in it.

```
C:\Users> Python
Python 3.7.3 (v3.7.3:ef4ec6ed12, Mar 25 2019, 21:26:53) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)] 
on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import gensim
```

see if that works.

**P.S.**

I would not recommend having two different compiler versions on a single OS as it creates a lot of commotion, and create incompatibility issues with program's made on one compiler with the other. And makes problems (like you mentioned) a lot more prevalent.

Comment: Thanks! I found out that I have two versions of Python: 3.7.1 and 3.7.2. The command `python` uses 3.7.2 and `py` uses 3.7.1. Which one should I uninstall?

Comment: Choose the one which has lesser installed modules.

Comment: Actually it's quite common to have multiple Python versions on a system, because different applications may require different Python versions. And as a programmer, you might want to test your application using multiple Python versions. However, the difficulty is in specifying which one to use. (The py launcher is a possible solution for that. Virtual environments are another solution. Just relying on the PATH is asking for troubles.)

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you have > 1 python installed in your machine. To install gensim (or any package) inside python command line, you can run below:

- type "python" then enter
- type "import subprocess" then enter
- type
  "subprocess.check_call(["python", '-m', 'pip', 'install', 'gensim'])"
  then enter

Sample below:

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.check_call(["python", '-m', 'pip', 'install', 'gensim'])
Collecting gensim
..
...
Installing collected packages: smart-open, gensim
Successfully installed gensim-3.7.3 smart-open-1.8.3
0
```

Comment: Isn't that the same as just running `python -m pip install gensim`?